# How to prevent the NodeJS event loop from exiting?

Tags: node.js

I've implemented a native function which takes a callback. NodeJS knows the interface, but it doesn't know anything about its implementation. This native function receives a callback and will call it when the result is ready. I don't want the event loop to exit while the callback hasn't been called.

Here is [an example of such a problem](https://github.com/madadam/rust_ffi_async_demo/blob/1e5b5b98c42f01b5acc10228a8446a747bb7f36d/js/index.js#L15).

Currently I need to do some I/O (even if it's a dumb timeout) to force NodeJS to wait for my function.

In [Boost.Asio I'd just instantiate a `work` object and destroy it when the callback is called](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__work.html). Boost.Asio's event loop wouldn't exit while this object is kept around. Is there a similar approach for NodeJS? What do I use in NodeJS (bonus if your answer doesn't mention timers)?

Comment: Your question is rather unclear. What do you mean Node knows nothing about it? How do you call it then? Is this a native module?

Comment: Can you please show the code that you've tried so far

Comment: Show your code that you have tried yet

Comment: Hi guys, I've updated the question. Sorry about making it "direct"/"quasi-objective", but I had bad experiences with long questions (in my experience, people run away from them and don't even try).

Comment: @vinipsmaker It is a fair point. But we can not help you without more explaination. You have to make it as clear as possible. Try to make use of markdown capabilities (title, emphasis, ...).

Comment: @PierreC.: I've added more info already (including a very small code base which shows the problem).

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://github.com/node-ffi/node-ffi/wiki/Node-FFI-Tutorial#async-library-calls) may be of help (although it may require a rewrite of your library code, not sure)?

Comment: @vinipsmaker updated for multiple callback

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way to do that would be writing a [C++ addon](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v5.x/api/addons.html) and using [one](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/prepare.html) [of](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/check.html) [the](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/idle.html) [handles](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/timer.html) offered by libuv (of course, the one that fits your requirements - see the official [documentation](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/index.html) for further details).

If you don't want to do that or if you can't do that (that is the case, if I've correctly understood the question), a viable solution not mentioned in the other answers is using `process.nextTick` to schedule a function that checks at each tick if the loop can expires or not.
see [here](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v5.x/api/process.html#process_process_nexttick_callback_arg) for further details about `process.nextTick`.

As a minimal, working, *never-ending* example:

```
var process = require('process')
var stop = false;
var f = function() { if(!stop) process.nextTick(f) }
f()
```

This way your function is in charge of setting the `stop` control variable once it finishes to execute, then the loop will stop.

If you have multiple callbacks to wait for, simply use a *counter* and check it looking for 0.
If you don't want to explicitly set and update the value of the counter each time you add a new function (error-prone), you can easily write a *launcher* to start your functions that increments the counter and schedules a check on the next tick if needed.
You could also pass a callback as an extra argument to your functions to notify when they are over, so that they have not to deal explicitly with the counter itself.

A plus of using a dedicated function that is scheduled on the next tick is that it's clear to the reader what you are doing.
On the other side, a fake server, a timeout scheduled in the future or an I/O stream resumed and never used are quite obscure, for the reader doesn't know immediately why you are doing that.

Comment: I took a look on the handles offered by libuv you mentioned and all of them are somewhat heavy (functions called at every iteration) and they are offered by NodeJS to JavaScript code already (i.e. no need to go native with C++). I think the cost could be decreased by using a counter like you proposed instead multiple `bool` variables and multiple handles, but still... I'll keep the timeout approach (miliseconds are ages of CPU cycles).

I'm choosing your answer because it seems you were the one who went further away. It gives me confidence that all options were explored.  Thanks.

Comment: @vinipsmaker Well, you are using nodejs, that is a layer over libuv and v8 to let you use JavaScript server side. Pointing out that an `if` costs too much sounds like a premature optimization. Anyway, I'm glad I helped you. :-)

Comment: @vinipsmaker The reason I didn't use the nextTick approach is the f() become a tight loop and will consume the whole cpu core.

Comment: It is a very readable solution, could be written also as: 
`(function endlessProcess() { process.nextTick(endlessProcess) })()`
But unlike `setTimeout`/`setInterval` functions, it utilizes all available CPU, which is not recommended.

Answer (score 6):

### Method 1: Create a dummy server(updated for multiple callback):

```
var counter = 0;

var server = require('net').createServer().listen(); // <-- Dummy server
console.log('Dummy server start.');

var ffi = require('ffi'),
    ref = require('ref')

var lib = ffi.Library('./libffi_async_demo', {
  'print_thread_id': [ 'void', [] ],
  'run_delayed': [ 'void', [ 'pointer' ] ],
});

var checkExit = function (){
  counter--;
  if (counter===0) {
    server.close(); // <-- exit Dummy Server
    console.log('Dummy server stop.');
  }
}

// Wrapper for lib.run_delay()
run_delay = function(cb) {
  counter++; // <-- increase counter
  lib.run_delayed(cb);
}

var callback1 = ffi.Callback('void', [], function() {
  console.log("js callback1 started");
  lib.print_thread_id();
  console.log("js callback1 finished");

  checkExit(); // <-- call at the end of each callback
})

var callback2 = ffi.Callback('void', [], function() {
  console.log("js callback2 started");
  lib.print_thread_id();
  console.log("js callback2 finished");

  checkExit(); // <-- call at the end of each callback
})

var callback3 = ffi.Callback('void', [], function() {
  console.log("js callback3 started");
  lib.print_thread_id();
  console.log("js callback3 finished");

  checkExit(); // <-- call at the end of each callback
})

run_delay(callback1); // use wrapper
run_delay(callback2); // use wrapper
run_delay(callback3); // use wrapper
```

### Method 2: Long timeout, callback end process

```
var timeout; // Hold timeout reference from setTimeout()

var ffi = require('ffi'),
    ref = require('ref')

var lib = ffi.Library('./libffi_async_demo', {
  'print_thread_id': [ 'void', [] ],
  'run_delayed': [ 'void', [ 'pointer' ] ],
});

var callback = ffi.Callback('void', [], function() {
  console.log("js callback started");
  lib.print_thread_id()
  console.log("js callback finished");

// Use one of the following 3:

//timeout.unref(); // <-- remove timer from Node event loop
//require('process').exit(); //<-- end process
  clearTimeout(timeout); // <-- cancel timer

})

lib.run_delayed(callback)

timeout = setTimeout(function() { }, 3600000); // <-- reasonably long timeout, eg. 1hr
```

Comment: With method 1 counter/wrapper, you can also incorporate kailniris or Mahai Potra techniques.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `stdin` Readable stream to hold on exiting the loop.

```
const callback = ffi.Callback('void', [], function() {
  // do your stuff here

  // switch stream out of flowing mode.
  process.stdin.pause();
});

// set stream into flowing mode ("old mode")
process.stdin.resume();

lib.run_delayed(callback);
```

**Reference**: the *Note* in https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdin

Comment: I like this answer. It'll save me a file descriptor per call. Gonna look if I can use it with multiple callbacks/calls.

Answer (score 2):

Start repl somewhere in your code, it will prevent your app from exit.

```
const repl = require('repl');
repl.start('> ')
```

When you are done just call

```
process.exit()
```

https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html

Answer (score 1):

create big timeout - it'll prevent node from exiting and also guards you from waiting indefinitely for (external to node) result:

```
var ffi = require('ffi'),
    ref = require('ref')

var ffiTimeout;
var lib = ffi.Library('./libffi_async_demo', {
  'print_thread_id': [ 'void', [] ],
  'run_delayed': [ 'void', [ 'pointer' ] ],
});

var ffiDidTimedOut = false;
var cancelFfi = function(timeoutCb) {
  return function() {
    ffiDidTimedOut = true;
    timeoutCb();
  }
}

var callback = ffi.Callback('void', [], function() {
  if (ffiDidTimedOut) {
    return; // sorry, we waited too long and already started doing something else
  }
  // all good, async ffi finished within expected time and we are back in our js land
  clearTimeout(ffiTimeout);
  lib.print_thread_id()
})

lib.run_delayed(callback)

// continueIfCancelledCallback is your continuation "what to do id ffi actually takes more than 20 seconds to run"
ffiTimeout = setTimeout(cancelFfi(continueIfCancelledCallback), 20000); // 20 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep a task running continuously, couldn't you simply create a setInterval which does nothing?

```
// Keep task running indefinitely:
setInterval(() => { ; }, 1000);
```

This seems to work for me.